# There is refuge in buddhism(buddha, dharma,sangha). What is refuge(triratna)in trika shaivism

Tags: shiva, kashmiri-shaivism

I know there para apara parapara in trika shaivism but I want a mantra like buddham sharanam gacchami which denotes refuge in buddha. What is refuge(triratna)in trika shaivism . If there is sanskrit verses in trika and other hindu sects specifically advaita and siddhanta shaivism then I want English translation and transliteration

Comment: Do you want mantra from Trika Shaivism or rest of Hinduism sects also? Pls. make it clear. Also make changes in your username and convert it into english so that rest of the community can address you directly and will be familiar with your name which is currently  unreadable due to language barrier.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar thank you for replying sir. Yes I want mantra from trika shaivism and other Hinduism sects if possible

Comment: @Christopher Since you mention other Hinduism sub-groups - There is a Vaishnava tradition in Southern part of India which believes in taking refuge in Vishnu. There is a prapatti of Sri Venkateswara (a form of Vishnu) that contains "Sree Venkatesha charanau saranam prapadhye", meaning, "I seek refuge at the feet of Sri Venkateswara"

Comment: There are many. Be more specific as to which Hindu tradition you are looking for.

Comment: @Swami Vishwananada trika shaivism

Comment: @zero thank you  for your answer . Is there some thing similar in trika shaivism